# How to passing in array parameter in windows batch?

Tags: batch-file, wmic

I'm trying to run this command in batch file:

```
wmic nicconfig where macaddress=somemacaddr call SetDNSServerSearchOrder (an array paramter)
```

For example:

```
set dnslist[1]="172.12.3.1"
set dnslist[2]="222.123.2.1"
...
set dnslist[x]="135.132.1.2"
```

We don't know the `dnslist` size before running the batch.
How could we passing the `dnslist` to `SetDNSServerSearchOrder` directly?

Comment: In case you know the number `x` of array elements: `for /L %%I in (1,1,%x%) do wmic ... !dnslist[%%I]!` (with [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) enabled); in case you do *not* know `x`: `for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%I in ('set dnslist[') do wmic ... %%I`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no arrays in batch files, per se. What you have there is just a collection of environment variables with the same prefix. There's nothing special about that.

How to pass them to a command depends on the command (e.g. are they space-separated, i.e. individual arguments, or comma-separated, or something else entirely?). You need to create a string from those variables that matches the format the program expects, e.g. when they should be space-separated, create a string the following way:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims==" %%A in ('set dnslist[') do set List=!List! %%B

wmic nicconfig where macaddress=somemacaddr call SetDNSServerSearchOrder %List%
```

Likewise for different delimiters. Delayed expansion should ideally be enabled at the very start of your script; no use creating a new local environment in the middle of it, usually.

If you want to call the command once for every entry in your "list", you don't need to create the delimiter-separated list in the first place, but rather just call the command directly with the entry.

Comment: This returns " %B %B %B" for me. Changing the code to `for /f "delims==" %%A in ('set dnslist[') do call set List=!List! %%A` works.